# SANE scanner access from inside a VM?

Tags: arch-linux, vmware, scanner, sane, canon

I'm using Arch inside VMware, and trying to connect to a Canon P-208 scanner.

I know this scanner to be supported, it has an entry in `/etc/sane.d/canon_dr.conf`, but it shows up as:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `v41:/dev/video0' is a Noname VMware Virtual USB Video Device virtual device
```

and then doesn't work:

```
$ scanimage --device "v41:/dev/video0" --format=png > test.png
scanimage: open of device v41:/dev/video0 failed: Invalid argument
$ scanimage --test
scanimage: sane_start: Invalid argument
```

Is there some way I can tell SANE to treat `v41:/dev/video0` as a P-208?